In a regression of Yon X, the value of X is fixed at 5. Find the regression equation
I wanted to know how this equation will look like and how we will be able to calculate the slope coefficient.

If $X$ is constant it is impossible to find the regression equation because regression coefficients $\beta_i$ are given by:
$$\beta_i = \frac{cov(Y, X_i)}{var(X_i)}$$
if you fix $X$ to be always 5 the variance of $X$ is 0 and division by 0 is undefined.

If there is no constant in the regression, then
$$ \widehat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_i x_iy_i}{\sum_i x_i^2} = 5\frac{\sum_i y_i}{5^2N} = \frac{\bar{y}}{5}.$$
It is not a slope, however, as $x_i$ is constant.
